# MTLAB runs a line of code in command window but returns an error if it is in editor, why is that and how to fix?

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB code which is a bit long, although this is a part of it I ran into problem:

```
I_pH_aa = pHLim_aa^k_aa /(y(36)^k_aa + pHLim_aa^k_aa);
I_pH_ac = pHLim_ac^k_ac /(y(36)^k_ac + pHLim_ac^k_ac);
I_pH_ac2 = pHLim_ac2^k_ac2 /(y(36)^k_ac2 + pHLim_ac2^k_ac2);
I_pH_h2 = pHLim_h2^k_h2 /(y(36)^k_h2 + pHLim_h2^k_h2);
I_IN_lim = 1.0/(1.0+K_S_IN/y(11));
I_h2_fa = 1.0/(1.0+y(8)/K_Ih2_fa);
I_h2_c4 = 1.0/(1.0+y(8)/K_Ih2_c4);
I_h2_pro = 1.0./(1.0+y(8)/K_Ih2_pro);
I_h2_ac = 1.0/(1.0+y(8)/K_Ih2_ac);
```

In last line, when I hit run the code I receive this error:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ADDE (line 243)
I_h2_ac = 1.0/(1.0+y(8)/K_Ih2_ac);
```

despite this error I tried to run the line in command window so I can understand if values are stored incorrectly since I assumed one of the values is not a scalar, that being said I got an answer and noticed there's nothing wrong with that line of code in first place.

I am now a bit confused of why this has happened and if there is a fix for it, as of now I am calculating the value in command window and substituted it with the value I get from MATLAB but I know this is not a fix at all.It worth mentioning that I have used this line in my code `global K_Ih2_ac` can it be because of this?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

I ran into problem in my code and debugged it so I can fix the issue but I noticed it wasn't an issue in the line of code I am getting an error, so I am now confused of what bring this issue.

Comment: Use the debugger to see values of variables while the program is running. Likely variables have a different value in the base workspace and in your program. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks for the link and answer, it seems you are right and they are different, I would have flag your answer as solution but sadly it's not possible, anyway how am I supposed to fix when such problems happens?

Comment: How to fix it depends on what you want to accomplish. Maybe `K_Ih2_ac` is supposed to be a scalar, and you need to fix where it’s created. Maybe you need to use `./` instead of `/`. I don’t know.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I asked my supervisor it seems another file which has created this value making the error, although it's not a fix but at least I now know what is causing the error, I tried different operators as you said and still didn't fix the issue however after terminating first process (file I mentioned sooner) it now works fine. Thanks for the help